# Existing Tensorflow model to use GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

I made a TensorFlow model without using CUDA, but it is very slow. Fortunately, I gained access to a Linux server (Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS), which has a Geforce 1060, also the necessary components are installed - I could test it, the CUDA acceleration is working.

The tensorflow-gpu package is installed (only 1.14.0 is working due to my code) in my virtual environment.

My code does not contain any CUDA-related snippets. I was assuming that if I run it in a pc with CUDA-enabled environment, it will automatically use it.

I tried the `with tf.device('/GPU:0'):` then reorganizing my code below it, didn't work. I got a strange error, which said only XLA_CPU, CPU and XLA_GPU is there. I tried it with XLA_GPU but didn't work.

Is there any guide about how to change existing code to take advantage of CUDA?

Comment: Post some example code here which works without CUDA and doesn't work with it enabled.

Comment: The way you described, you can use the advantage of GPU, but not CUDA, here is a course from NVIDIA of how to accelerate you computations with CUDA: https://courses.nvidia.com/courses/course-v1:DLI+C-AC-02+V1/about

Answer (score 0):

Not enough to give exact answer.

Have you installed tensorflow-gpu separately? Check using pip list.

Cause, initially, you were using tensorflow (default for CPU).
Once you use want to use Nvidia, make sure to install tensorflow-gpu.

Sometimes, I had problem having both installed at the same time. It would always go for the CPU. But, once I deleted the tensorflow using "pip uninstall tensorflow" and I kept only the GPU version, it worked for me.